# Why "`trade".replace("`", "") is "trade" resulting False and "".join(list("`trade")[1:]) is "trade" also False

Tags: python, string, str-replace, string-comparison

I wondering why the following tests return False:
Suppose I have 2 simple strings:

```
str0 = "trade"
str1 = "`trade"
```

I don't understand why the following tests in python return False:

```
str1.replace("`", "") is str0
```

And,

```
"".join(list(str1)[1:]) is str0 => False
```

Thanks for your education!

Comment: `is` is not the same as `==` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is

Comment: This is due to an optimization in the interpreter. Always use `==` to compare values!

Comment: _almost_ always use `==` to compare values. `None`, `True` and `False` are all singletons with a single identity.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, `is` compares two objects in memory, `==` compares their values. Since your two variables are stored at two different places in memory, your comparison using `is` evaluates to false.